# find - No such file or directory albeit it exists

Tags: find, osx

I run the following command on a directory:

```
find . -name "*.pyc" -type f -delete
```

however it prints this

```
find: -delete: unlink(./tests/unit/framework/__init__.pyc): No such file or directory
```

for every file in the directory recursively. My question is, if it is able to resolve a file name, why does it not find it when trying to delete it?

Comment: Does `ls -l ./tests/unit/framework/__init__.pyc` show anything unusual?

Comment: This is what I get in return `-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 165 Jun 3 01:37 ./tests/unit/framework/__init__.pyc –`

Comment: What filesystem did you run this command on?

Comment: The primary filesystem on OS X : HFS+

Comment: What is it you want to do?  Delete files with extension *.pyc recursively ?